# Multiple derivatives to multiple tables

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I have such database structure:

Class `Company` has a property `CompanyInfoTableName`

Also I have class CompanyInfo which is not mapped to database directly.

There are tables with names like Company001Info, Company002Info and so on. These tables contain records of type CompanyInfo.

Before now the third party ORM framework was used to map these relations. For each CompanyInfo table the ORM framework used to create separate dynamic classes. To get CompanyInfo for each of Companies I had to use CompanyInfoTableName property to load needed data.

Now I want to use Entity Framework instead of this third party ORM framework. Database redesign is not an option.

Is there a way in Entity Framework to map my current database structure to Entity Framework model as painful as possible?

Thank you

Comment: Yes, this will be really painful... AFAIK there is no such support in EF. So you either have to redesign DB, or use different ORM

Comment: Use your current ORM. EF has no support for this - especially if you expect that your tables can be added dynamically which I guess you do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I found is to use DevExpress XPO for tables with dynamic column count. All other tables are mapped to EntityFramework classes.